# ValueError: All of the arrays in `x` should have the same length. Found a pair with: len(x[0]) = 97, len(x[?]) = 205

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184834/value-error-input-arrays-should-have-the-same-number-of-samples-as-target-array) but the answers didn't help.

I have the following code:

```
LABELS = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

data = []
labels = []

num_classes = 10
for i in range(num_classes):

    filenames = glob.glob(str(i) + '_*.png')

    for j in range(len(filenames)):
        im_gbr = cv2.imread(filenames[j])
        im = cv2.cvtColor(im_gbr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        data.append(im)
        labels.append(i)

# Normalise
x_min = np.min(data[0], axis=tuple(range(data[0].ndim-1)), keepdims=True)
x_max = np.max(data[0], axis=tuple(range(data[0].ndim-1)), keepdims=True)
data[0] = (data[0] - x_min)/ (x_max - x_min)

lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
                                                  test_size=0.33, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# construct the training image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20, zoom_range=0.15,
                         width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.15,
                         horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

# initialize the optimizer and model
EPOCH = 100
opt = Adam(lr=1e-4, decay=1e-4 / EPOCH)
model = StridedNet.build(width=96, height=96, depth=3,
                         classes=len(lb.classes_), reg=l2(0.0005))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
              metrics=["accuracy"])
# train the network

H = model.fit(x=aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=32),
              validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // 32,
              epochs=EPOCH)
```

Also:

len(trainX) = 66

len(testX) = 33

len(trainY) = 66

len(testY) = 33

When I run the code I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: All of the arrays in `x` should have the same length. Found a pair with: len(x[0]) = 97, len(x[?]) = 205
```

The error corresponds to `x=aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=32)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make all your images the same size so after

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(im_gbr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# add the code
height=96     # set your desired image height in pixels
width= 96      # set your desired image width in pixels
im = cv2.resize(im, (width, height))
```

Not sure why you are doing normalization. You can just add rescale=1/255 in the image data generator. You are using categorical_cross entropy as you loss. I think if that is the case you should use lb=OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).

Comment: I added resize in the loop but then I got this error: `ValueError: 'x' (images tensor) and 'y' (labels) should have the same length. Found: x.shape = (128, 128, 3), y.shape = (66, 10)`.